Unable to mount Android phone via SSH on Ubuntu 20.04
Following all of the steps outlined in this answer, on the thread titled How to mount Android external storage over WiFi instead of USB, I still can't figure out how to wirelessly mount my Android phone via SSH on Ubuntu 20.04.
After installing SSH/SFTP Server - Terminal on my phone, I can successfully connect to the server via SSH, but am unable to mount it as a filesystem.
When entering the URI ssh://obalaban@192.168.50.13:2222 in Thunar, nothing happens, while when adding the path to the top-level directory, /sdcard, initially the filesystem appears to be mounted, only to open up a blank file named 'sdcard' in a text editor at the putative mount point, but nothing actually is mounted.
echo obalaban | sshfs -o password_stdin -p 2222 obalaban@192.168.50.237:/ /mnt/samsung
read: Connection reset by peer

I fixed this error by editing /etc/fuse.conf and enabling the line user_allow_other.
I am using public key authentication and tried copying my key to the remote filesystem, but was unsuccessful. Normal ssh login works fine. So I tried debugging in sshfs:
sshfs -odebug,sshfs_debug,loglevel=debug -o allow_other,default_permissions -p 2222 obalaban@192.168.50.237:~/ /mnt/samsung
SSHFS version 2.10.0
FUSE library version: 2.9.9
nullpath_ok: 0
nopath: 0
utime_omit_ok: 0
executing <ssh> <-x> <-a> <-oClearAllForwardings=yes> <-ologlevel=debug> <-oPort=2222> <-2> <obalaban@192.168.50.237> <-s> <sftp>
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.50.237 [192.168.50.237] port 2222.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/obalaban/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /home/obalaban/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/obalaban/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/obalaban/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/obalaban/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/obalaban/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/obalaban/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/obalaban/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/obalaban/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/obalaban/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/obalaban/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/obalaban/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/obalaban/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/obalaban/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.11
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version SSH Server - Banana Studio
debug1: no match: SSH Server - Banana Studio
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.50.237:2222 as 'obalaban'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: ecdh-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:JD2yGa1+aF6yPMMZpeFGBkMHM5qLhfBo5mRERuyOOT4
debug1: Host '[192.168.50.237]:2222' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/obalaban/.ssh/known_hosts:9
debug1: rekey out after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/obalaban/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:W4wAsxdFXXWQJMU9k54+cHDYrvXrVo9hZEbLXkRySOM
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/obalaban/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/obalaban/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/obalaban/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/obalaban/.ssh/id_ed25519 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/obalaban/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/obalaban/.ssh/id_xmss 
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password,keyboard-interactive,publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/obalaban/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:W4wAsxdFXXWQJMU9k54+cHDYrvXrVo9hZEbLXkRySOM
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password,keyboard-interactive,publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/obalaban/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/obalaban/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/obalaban/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /home/obalaban/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /home/obalaban/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /home/obalaban/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
Password authentication
Password: 
debug1: Authentication succeeded (keyboard-interactive).
Authenticated to 192.168.50.237 ([192.168.50.237]:2222).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending subsystem: sftp
Server version: 3
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Transferred: sent 2624, received 1512 bytes, in 0.1 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 29627.5, received 17071.9
debug1: Exit status 0



I wonder why someone downvotes this question - how does this help? At least I'd expected a comment, what is missing. This seems to be a growing virus
